# Find those tuples in which the second element is maximum among all values with same first element

Tags: python, tuples

How to sanitize a given list of tuples, such that only tuples with maximum values are listed.

```
mytup = [('a',2),('a',6),('b',4),('a',4),('b',10),('c',4),('c',6),('c',8),('d',12),('d',10)]
```

Result

```
[('a',6), ('b', 10), ('c', 8), ('d', 12)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it into a dictionary:

```
mytup = [('a',2),('a',6),('b',4),('a',4),('b',10),('c',4),('c',6),('c',8),('d',12),('d',10)]
d = {}

for key, value in mytup:
    if d.get(key) < value:  # d.get(key) returns None if the key doesn't exist
        d[key] = value      # None < float('-inf'), so it'll work

result = d.items()
```

Comment: Thanks. That is simple and elegant. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
dict = {}
for key, val in mytup:
    try:
        if dict[key] < val:
            dict[key] = val
    except IndexError:
        dict[key] = val
```

Answer (score 0):

Itertools is your friend, one line solution:

```
from itertools import groupby
print [ max(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(mytup), lambda x: x[0] )]
```

Results:

```
[('a', 6), ('b', 10), ('c', 8), ('d', 12)]
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the `key` in `sorted`. Works perfectly without it. :)

Comment: `sorted` is an `O(NlogN)` operation.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary your solution approach is to change list to dict and then back to list. Also you use OrderedDict, that is O(NLogN). My solution use a sort. OP will choice ... any of both :(  Thanks about your comments.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija, thanks about your comment. Changed and improved answer.